# Get value from span inside list with id

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code where I want to retrieve the value of the **span** element inside an anchor tag, inside a list element with an id.

```js
parseInt($('#top_cart_button.span').text(), 10);
```

```html
<li id="top_cart_button">
  <a href="default.asp?cmd=showCart" rel="nofollow">
    <span>€ 55,00</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

How can I do it?
Thank you

Comment: instead of a dot, use a space - `#top_cart_button span` - with your dot your selector means an element with an id of top cart button AND a class of span; with the space, your selector says a span inside an element with an id of top cart button.  [More information about css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: Thanks, it works with space before span if the value is 0,00. It didn't work in the first place because if the value is greater then 1 the cart adds the € symbol. See edited version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#top_cart_button.span` will try to find the first element with class span that is a child of the element with id `top_cart_button`. You want to find the element with the tag `span` and not the class. To do so, remove the `.`. Then, to remove the extra character, you can extract only the numbers from the input using the `extractDigits` function below.

Here's a working example:

```js
let InputText = $('#top_cart_button span').text();
let InputDigitsOnly = extractDigits(InputText);

function extractDigits(input) {
  return input.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
}

console.log(parseInt(InputDigitsOnly, 10));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="top_cart_button">
  <a href="default.asp?cmd=showCart" rel="nofollow">
    <span>€ 55,00</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

**EDIT**:

```js
var prezzo = parseInt($('.mainPriceAmount').text().split(",")[0], 10);
var InputText = $('#top_cart_button span').text().split(",")[0];
var InputDigitsOnly = extractDigits(InputText);

function extractDigits(input) {
  return input.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
}
var carrello = parseInt(InputDigitsOnly, 10);
var somma = prezzo + carrello;
var customLink = '<img alt="Hello" src="https://ps.w.org/click-fraud-check/assets/icon-128x128.png?rev=2160665"/>';

if (prezzo >= 199 || somma >= 199) {
  $('#customHTML').show();
  $('#sped').html(customLink);
}
```

```css
#customHTML {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Cart:</th>
  <td>
    <p id="top_cart_button"><a href="#"><span>€ 199,00</span></a></p>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="price">
  <th scope="row">Price:</th>
  <td data-label="">
    <h3 class="mainPrice"><span class="mainPriceAmount">99,00</span></h3>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="customHTML" style="display:none">
  <th scope="row">Shipping:</th>
  <td>
    <p id="sped"></p>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm ... but only in console. I now have a problem with the whole script, I'm sure I'm  missing something, it doesn't do what it should. Do i have to ask a new question?
The code can be seen https://jsfiddle.net/cgabrielle/7fb3mt0g/5/#&togetherjs=v4oUjiF5le

Comment: @GabrielC. edited my answer, adding your fixed jsfiddle.

Comment: I found another issue with this script... when the price is > 1000 is formatted like this 1,000.00. I've tried parseFloat('.mainPriceAmount'.replace(/, /g, '')); but it doesn't work. Can someone please help me with that one too? Thanks

Comment: @GabrielC.I would suggest asking another question since this post is already pretty full.

Answer (score 0):

`span` is not a class but an element, this works:

```
parseInt($('#top_cart_button span').text(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li id="top_cart_button">
  <a href="default.asp?cmd=showCart" rel="nofollow">
    <span>0,00</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

If its necessarily inside an anchor tag. (meaning if you want to ignore other spans that are not inside the "a" tag. )

```
$("li#top_cart_button a span").text();  //or html() if you are trying to get html.
```

and same for the function

```
parseInt($("li#top_cart_button a span").text(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost nearly there just remove the "." between top_cart_button and span.

```
$('$('#top_cart_button span')')
```

Gets the span "element" in top_cart_button whereas your statement has a "." prefix which gets the first element with span "class" name.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getDigitsFromString(str){
  const regex = /\d+[.]?\d+/g;
  const result = regex.exec(str.replace(',','.'));
  if(result[0] !== null){
    return parseFloat(result[0]);
  }
  return;
}

console.log(getDigitsFromString($('#top_cart_button > a > span').text()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="top_cart_button">
  <a href="default.asp?cmd=showCart" rel="nofollow">
    <span>€ 55,55</span>
  </a>
</li>
```